# Windows application certification kit fails

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, wack

I have an application for which I have created the App Packages and launched the Windows App Certification Kit. The kit fails testing the application on my development system.

It gave me following error:

```
App launch tests

• Error Found: The app launch test detected the following errors:◦Failed to launch App.
• Impact if not fixed:  An app that fails to launch presents a poor user experience, and will not be accepted by the Windows Store.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I log in as system admin,App launch test got passed.Previously i was using user credentials of domain user which was not having administrative right.

Hence i found that login user should have full admin access for that particular system where we try to launch the app.